# Ocultar elemento ao imprimir página

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

Tenho uma página de um relatório de produtos que converto ela para pdf usando o wkhtmltopdf.

Meu problema é ao gerar o pdf quero colocar uma div com um banner no final de categoria, se a categoria não ocupar toda a página.
EX: relatório com 10 página
   na décima página os produtos ocuparam  apenas metade da página, então coloca  um banner.

Caso os produtos ocupe toda a página não mostre o banner. nem mesmo na próxima.

Comment: Você precisa postar ao menos algum exemplo do código que está imprimindo para que alguém consiga dar um solução ao seu caso...

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se a pergunta está coerente com o título da mesma, mas, no caso de ocultar ou tratar elementos na versão de impressão vc só precisa tratar com css.

Segue um exemplo

```
/*CSS para impressão*/
@media print {
  .elemento{
  display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: pelo o que entendi do título da pergunta, sua resposta está certa, pela descrição, ele quer outra coisa, mas que também precisará desta informação.